# Shopping cart "add to cart" button style issue

Tags: css

I'm experiencing some difficulties understanding what is happening here:

The green color and hover effect is being applied to the add to cart button on the products list page

http://www.jkadengeart.com/gallery/

but is not being applied to the add to cart button on the single product pages

http://www.jkadengeart.com/gallery/p...n-prints-only/

Also, when I do float:left, the button still remains flush right.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: post your code, jsfiddle.net is better so that we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue 01

In gallery page you are giving green color exlusively for `#mp_product_list input.mp_button_addcart`
But there is no div with the same ID in `single` page.

So, Add or remove the ID

like

```
input.mp_button_addcart {
...
}
```

or

```
#mp_product_list input.mp_button_addcart, 
#single_container input.mp_button_addcart {
    ...
}
```

### Issue 02

Float left is not working because you have given `float:right` to `form`

```
form.mp_buy_form {
float: right;
}
```

Change it to `left`

```
form.mp_buy_form {
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this please add `below` `selector` `position:absolute;`

**css**

```
    #mp_product_list input.mp_button_addcart {
        margin: 0 0 50px;
        position: absolute;
    }
.mp_grid .mp_product_detail {

    margin-top: 63px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```